# Passing variable to BackgroundWorker and use the same value later

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net

I create multiple `BackgroundWorker` within a `for`-loop and each of them needs to know a special value. To simplify, it is just `i` in this example. When the `BackgroundWorker` is finished, I need to read that `i` again. I thought of subclassing `BackgroundWorker` and creating a class `MyBW` for that purpose which is able to store the `i` as `value`.

My example below works, but I am interested, if this is the best way to do this?

*Edit:* I have to add, that the variable I need to pass is a simple `String`, not a large object.

**Fully working minimal example**

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace MultiThreadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MyBW bw = new MyBW();
                bw.value = i;
                bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
                bw.DoWork += delegate(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs eargs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Thread {0} started", bw.value));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(bw.value * 1000);
                };
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs eargs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Thread {0} finished", bw.value));
                };

                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            // Only as a run loop that I can see the output.
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Sleeping...");
            }
        }
    }

    class MyBW : System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Here I store the value.
        /// </summary>
        public int value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, this doesn't look good. Unfortunatelly I cannot rewrite it with`async/await` but let's wait for someone who can ;-D

Comment: Do you *have* to use BackgroundWorker? Unless you're targeting an old .NET version, you really should be using newer constructs.

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: Have a look at `Task`, `BackgroundWorker` are really oldschool. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` already has a mechanism for passing and retrieving arguments.  The [`DoWorkEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) has a property for a passed in method argument and a property for the DoWork result.  The [`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) has a property for retrieving the result.  No sub-classing is necessary, although you may need to make a custom container if you need to pass/return more than one object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker ();
  bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
  bw.DoWork += delegate(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs eargs)
  {
    int i = (int)eargs.Arugment;  //get argument
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Thread {0} started", bw.value));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(bw.value * 1000);
    eargs.Result = i;            //set result
  };
  bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs eargs)
  {
    int i = (int)eargs.Arugment;  //get argument
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Thread {0} finished", i));
  };

  bw.RunWorkerAsync(i);
}
```

Comment: there is a bug; you defined an `i` inside the loop that already defines it

Comment: but aways it's a questionable design because a `BackgroundWorker` needs to be disposed and it's hard manage it with the OP's loop

Comment: If you are referring to the `i` inside the delegates, I was thinking that it would mask the outer for loop `i` since it is in the inner scope of a delegate.  If not though, it is trivial to rename.  As for the bgworkers in a loop, I've tried it before and yes, the results were mixed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with, thanks to the many hints in the comments and answer is as following:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultiThreadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Run the async method 10 times.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                RunSomethingAsync(i);
            }

            // Only as a run loop so that the output is visible.
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Sleeping...");
            }
        }

        static async void RunSomethingAsync(int i)
        {
            int z = 99;
            Task t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(i * 5000);
                z = 77;
            });
            // Output is always 99.
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("started thread {0}: {1}", i, z));
            await t;
            // Output is always 77.
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("finished thread {0}: {1}", i, z));
        }
    }
}
```